# How to remove all HTML in code and shorten it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have HTML like:

```
<div id='post'>
   <div class="">This is text</div>
   <div class="">This is image</div>
   <div class="">This is video</div>
   <div class="">This is video</div> 
   <div class="">This is something</div>
</div>
```

I want use javascript to take a shorten of this is `id='post'`.

For example after shorten I have result like:

```
This is text. This is image.
```

It is not :

```
This is text.
This is image.
```

Many thanks.

Comment: try $("post").text();

Comment: You lose the formatting because you take only the text.

Comment: everyone understand my intention? Why vote down me? Downvoter comment?

Comment: @user2728514 The reason your question is being heavily down-voted is because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't downvote this but it could be because you haven't demonstrated any attempt to do this yourself. This is a question/answer site - not a howto site. That and your example is not indicative of your question

Comment: You're not trying to do what you think you're trying to do... you're actually trying to create `this is text.<br />this is image.` assuming you're viewing it in a browser (otherwise it's something like `this is text.\r\nthis is image.`)

Comment: Please explain a little what exactly you want and in what situation.. Do you want the first code or the second? Why two? Is it always two? Is the two just an example and you actually want N or all of the lines? What determines how many lines?

Answer (score 1):

For the first 2 DIVs;

```
var string = $("#post > div:lt(2)").map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).toArray().join(" ");
```

Comment: But this does not contain the newlines... from your question I thought you did want the newlines... O_o Derp, must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in every situation, but in this specific situation you can use something like this

```
var text = "";
$('#post > div').each(function() {
    text += $(this).text() + "\n";
});
```

After that `text` will contain your string with newlines.